# If we take estimated parameters from an MCMC and plug it back into the likelihood to draw new observations, what does the histogram approximate?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior

Suppose we have the following set-up and we conduct an MCMC on it.

## Likelihood:

$$
X\sim  ~ Gamma(\alpha,\beta)
$$

## Prior:

$$
\alpha \sim Unif(0,10)
$$
$$
\beta \sim Gamma(0.5,0.5)
$$

Assume the MCMC over $M$ iterations gives us estimates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ where $\widehat{\alpha} = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_M)$ and $\widehat{\beta} = (\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_M)$.

Assume we iteratively for $i = \{1, \ldots, M\}$:

- Take $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ and sample a value of $x_i \sim Gamma(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$

If we plot the density of these $(x_1, \ldots, x_M)$, what is it approximating? Is it the **posterior predictive**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is called the posterior predictive distribution.  Mathematically, the histogram is approximating the following distribution

$$ p(\tilde{y} \vert y) = \int p(\tilde{y} \vert \theta) p(\theta \vert y) \, d\theta$$

You'll note the first part of the integrand is the likelihood and the second is the posterior.  This integral is integrating over all $\theta$ drawn from the posterior and plugged into the likelihood.

Comment: Thanks. For my procedure above, the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be plugged into the likelihood is taken iteratively. Is it necessary for me to sample $\alpha$ and $\beta$ randomly before plugging in? Is there a difference between randomly sampling the posterior parameters vs. taking them one by one iteratively up to $M$? Thanks!

Comment: If you've obtained the alpha and beta through MCMC, then they are considered pseudorandom draws from the posterior and you can perform the procedure iteratively.